# baseline-on-migrate with Flyway and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, h2, flyway

I have seen this posted before but I had already implemented the solutions offered and so I am asking again with more detail to my specific situation.  I am trying to integrate Flyway in my SpringBoot app (using H2).  I have added the following to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and to application.properties I have tried both:

```
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
```

and:

```
flyway.baseline-on-migrate=false
```

but I consistently get the error:

`Found non-empty schema(s) "PUBLIC" without schema history table! Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.`

I have tried a variety of other solutions I've seen posted, including adding Flyway as a plugin and not just dependency in the POM, but nothing seems to be working.  Does anyone know what I'm missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using ?

Comment: Oh you are absolutely right!  I was using 2.1.3 (with Java 11).  I had heard that most of those compatibility issues had been resolved but I guess not.  I downed it to 1.5.19 (and Java 8) and it's working fine now.  Know of any way to get around that though?  Thanks so much for setting me straight!

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit old question, but in Spring boot 2.x you should use `spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate = true` instead